# How to format date in hana

Tags: date-format, hana

I need to format date in my hana sql, but I don't know how to. Something like this:

```
 SELECT
 DATE_FORMAT(DATAS,'%Y-%m') as Dat 
,sum(SALES_VALUE) as Venda
,sum(SALES_QTY) as Qtd
,sum(SALES_VALUE) / sum(SALES_QTY) as  Preco
FROM looqdata.data_store_sales as s
inner join
looqdata.data_store_cad as c
on s.STORE_CODE = c.STORE_CODE
where 1=1
and DATAS between '2016-01-04' and '2016-02-10'
and s.STORE_CODE in  (1,2) 
group by DATE_FORMAT(DATAS,'%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Date-data types in SAP HANA, just as in most other DBMS, don't have a specific formatting associated with them.
The formatting is part of the output rendering process and locale dependent setting usually come into play here. You may check my [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/04/21/community-criss-cross-puzzle-posting-in-multiple-locales/) on this.

If you want to force a specific format and accept that the data type becomes a string data type, then using conversion functions like `TO_VARCHAR()` [reference docu link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20f226a1751910149edd8969c469d54d.html) can be used.

E.g.

```
SELECT 
      TO_VARCHAR (TO_DATE('2009-12-31'), 'YYYY/MM/DD') "to varchar" 
FROM DUMMY;
```

Converts a date string from format `YYYY-MM-DD` to date format `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Answer (score 5):

As Lars explained you can use TO_VARCHAR() function for converting a date expression into a desired format

If you want to convert a date which is already in a column of data type DATE, you don't need an additional TO_DATE() conversion
In such a case, you can directly use TO_VARCHAR() for date format conversion in SQLScript

Please check following SQLScript code on your development SAP HANA database

```
create column table ProductValue (
Product      varchar(10),
Date     date,
Value  int
);
insert into ProductValue values ('P1','20171001',10);

select *, TO_VARCHAR(Date,'DD.MM.YY')  from ProductValue;
select *, TO_VARCHAR(Date,'DD.MM.YYYY')  from ProductValue;
select *, TO_VARCHAR(Date,'YYYY-MM')  from ProductValue;
select *, TO_VARCHAR(Date,'YYYY-MM-DD')  from ProductValue;
select *, TO_VARCHAR(Date,'YYYY/MM/DD')  from ProductValue;
select *, TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(Date),'YYYY/MM/DD')  from ProductValue;
```