# How to format date in where?

Tags: sql, hana, sapb1

I have this script:

```
select * from OPDN A 
where A."DocDate" between '2020/01/01' and '2020/01/31'
```

How to achieve the format "MM/DD/YYYY" in the WHERE clause?

```
select * from OPDN A 
where A."DocDate" between '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020'
```

The column `DocDate` is of type `TimeStamp`.

Comment: which database you're using?

Comment: SQL Script in SAP Hana

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format date in hana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981250/how-to-format-date-in-hana)

Comment: @CarloAngeles Be clear what u asked ..i think u have issue with date formatting while using BETWEEN clause.. `try like Between to_date('01-01-2020','MM-DD-YYYY')`

Comment: @Shalini I've already tried this but still getting error.

Comment: What error message do you get? And what data type is the  column of ? Is it a `date` data type or a `VARCHAR` string column that just stores a date?

Comment: @Lars Br. Error in parsing '01/01/2020' in Format 'MM/DD/YYYY' I think i can't change the format value.

Comment: @LarsBr.Have u tried changing date format to `'MM/DD/YYYY'`

Answer (score 3):

If the column data type is `TIMESTAMP` as the OP has written in a comment to Sandra Rossi's excellent answer then there are actually three conversions required to make the selection work as expected.

1. turn the first selection parameter (between a ...) into a date
2. turn the second selection parameter (between ... and b) into a date
3. turn the timestamp column `DocDate` into a date

This looks like this:

```
select 
        * 
from 
     OPDN A 
where 
    to_date(A."DocDate") between to_date('01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                             and to_date('01/31/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

The conversion of the selection parameters with the help of format-strings should be obvious, and the result is the same information in a SQL date data type.
The third conversion (`to_date(a."DocDate")`) might be surprising, but is rather important.

The way the selection is *meant* to work is to include everything from the very start of the selection period to the very end. If the input filters are simply converted to timestamps then they will have the time-component of `00:00` (midnight), as no specifics about the time of day are provided.
This will lead to all "DocDate" values **after** midnight to be excluded.

The correct level of comparison here is **date**, therefore the "DocDate" also needs to be converted to the hour-less `date` data type.

p.s. I just realized that the selection criteria are given in `MM/DD/YYYY` format which is probably the reason for the conversion error the OP received earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what is the type and format of the column `DocDate`.

1. In SAP ERP softwares (R/3, ECC, S/4HANA), the dates were historically defined as NVARCHAR types of 8 characters, with the format 'YYYYMMDD'.
2. In SAP Business One, I don't know...
3. In SAP HANA database, there are also four specific types ([SAP Library "Datetime Data Types"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/3f81ccc7e35d44cbbc595c7d552c202a.html)): `DATE`, `TIME`, `SECONDDATE`, `TIMESTAMP`.

Solutions for each case:

1. If `DocDate` type is **NVARCHAR 8** with format YYYYMMDD: `select * from OPDN A where A."DocDate" between '20200101' and '20200131'`
2. In SAP Business One, I don't know...
3. If `DocDate` type is **DATE**: `select * from OPDN A where A."DocDate" between to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYY') and to_date('01/31/2020', 'DD/MM/YYY')`

Comment: I tried the solution 3 but I guess I can't achive this because the DocDate is TimeStamp.

Comment: @CarloAngeles Please discard my answer as `DocDate` type is TIMESTAMP and I don't answer this case. Moreover your SAP software seems to be SAP Business One (you confirm?), and I don't answer this case neither.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, it can do that

```
select * from OPDN A 
where to_date(A."DocDate", 'DD/MM/YYY') between to_date('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYY') and to_date('01/31/2020', 'DD/MM/YYY');
```