# How to convert a date to string in SAP HANA calculated column?

Tags: hana, hana-graphical-calculation-view

I want to add months to a date (YYYYMMDD), which is a string currently '20190101'.

to add months i use:
addmonths(date('20190101'),12)

which would give me "2020-01-01" as a date

But I only want "202001" as my final output. I tried doing the below but doesn't seem to work!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
TO_VARCHAR(ADDMONTHS(DATE('20190101'), 12), 'YYYYMM')
```

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985953/18667225